# DeclareLocalOption of kvoptions does not work

Tags: kvoptions

Consider the following tst package:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[2011/06/27]
\ProvidesPackage{tst}[2014/12/01 v1.0 tst package]

\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\SetupKeyvalOptions{%
  family=TST,
  prefix=TST@}

\DeclareBoolOption{abc}
\DeclareComplementaryOption{cba}{abc}
\DeclareLocalOption{abc}
\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\newcommand*{\showit}%
  {\ifbool{TST@abc}%
     {TRUE}%
     {FALSE}}
```

When I use the package the compilation gives an error stating that 
    `\DeclareLocalOption`
is undefined. However the documentation states that this macro exists.
Changing it to `\DeclareLocalOptions` (mind the extra `s`) solves the problem
but this macro is intended for a comma separated list of options. Another
solution seems to use the internal `\KVO@DeclareLocalOption` macro. Is this
an error in the `kvoptions` package?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bug that will be fixed in a future release of `kvoptions`.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `\DeclareLocalOptions`. It was a bug, that `\DeclareLocalOption` was not defined in `kvoptions`.

Comment: 'Nobody' except the OP? [Were I the OP, your post would come across to me as saying 'nobody important'. I'm guessing that is not what you mean to convey!]

Comment: @cfr It's a little different to use an undefined command for an expected different functionality ;-). The feature should be present for five years (2009/07/21 v3.3), but where are the bug reports?

Comment: I think you are not seeing it from the OP's point of view. The OP tried to use a command with the reasonable belief that it was defined. So to say 'nobody' implies that the OP does not count as anybody at all. Why not just say that nobody *needs* the singular form, which is surely true.

Comment: @cfr I have removed the sentence.